# Customizing pieces management modal in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am using the [`apostrophe-samples` Github project](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-samples) to do some tests regarding the pieces modal customization. So far, I've added filters [as explained in the tutorials](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html#filters-for-the-quot-manage-quot-modal), and added columns as seen in the `apostrophe-pieces` source code (I think it would be an interesting topic to add to the tutorials, IMHO).

However, I have a couple of doubts, given the example that *specialists* `joinByArray` *products* and *products* `joinByArrayReverse` *specialists*:

- Can columns be sorted in any way through the UI (e.g., an option that enables sorting by clicking the table header) or does it rely entirely on the piece's `defaultSort`?
- Can other fields other than the title be added as filters? I was able to add `_specialists` as products filter, displaying the title, but I'm wondering if a different field could be used.
- Can **reverse** joins be added as filters? As said, I was able to add `_specialists` as products filter, but not the other way around.
- Can joins/reverse joins be added as columns? If I add '_specialists' I column, I get displayed an array like `[Object]`, not the title as in the filter.

Comment: Can you clarify your question about _specialists as a products filter? It sounds like you successfully added _specialists as a products filter (which is not title), and your question is really about how that filter works and what it displays, and not about picking fields other than the title of a product to filter on...?

Comment: Regarding the _specialists as products filter, I added to the `products` index page the following code: 
`addFilters: [{
      name: '_specialists',
      label: 'Specialists'
    }]`.

The filter works, but it automatically displays in the dropwodn the specialist title. I was just wondering whether a different field from the join rather than the title could be used as filter. I hope I'm explaining myself better now.

Comment: On the other hand, adding `addFilters: [{ name: '_products', label: 'Products' }]` to the `specialists` index, which would mean filtering by the reverse join, did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Can columns be sorted in any way through the UI (e.g., an option that enables sorting by clicking the table header) or does it rely entirely on the piece's defaultSort?"

Not at present, no. The intent was to provide this feature but it has not been built out so far, as surprisingly it hasn't been a pressing need for our own clients although it is certainly a common feature.

It would make a good community contribution, or it could be sponsored via apostrophe enterprise support. It likely wouldn't take long to add.

> "Can other fields other than the title be added as filters? I was able to add _specialists as products filter, displaying the title, but I'm wondering if a different field could be used."

Not currently, but this one would be an easy PR. Here's the [relevant line of code in apostrophe-schemas/index.js](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas/index.js#L2290). You have access to the `field` object here, so you could easily do a PR to look in a different property of `doc` if `field.filterLabelField` is set, let's say, still falling back to `title`.

> "Can reverse joins be added as filters? As said, I was able to add _specialists as products filter, but not the other way around."

Not currently. In `lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas/index.js` you'll see that there is currently no `addFilter` property for these. The implementation is possible. The code would need to fetch the chosen doc on the reverse side, get the id or array of ids it joins to, and chain a `.and({ $in... })` call.

> "Can joins/reverse joins be added as columns? If I add '_specialists' as a column, I get displayed an array like [Object], not the title as in the filter."

This one is supported today. You need to set a `partial` property for the column. This is just a function that accepts the value of the column and returns a string. For instance:

```
addColumns: [
  {
    name: '_specialists',
    partial: specialists => specialists.map(specialist => specialist.title).join(' ')
  }
]
```

It would be nice to have a better default behavior for this case than assuming it's OK to show it as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, as always! I will take into account your difficulty evaluation of possible PRs.